# Defining cache key for caching in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, caching, model-view-controller

How can i create caching key, if I have String array of unknown length as an argument like

```
    String[] name = new String[2]{"Ramesh","Suresh"};

    @cacheable(value="cacheStorage", key="#????")
    public void getSurName(String[] name){}
```

if I pass String array to method getSurName, how to define the key for it. Mind you all, the size of an array is unknown.

Comment: Have you tried `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(#args)`? Yes, it's quite complicated

Comment: Also, are you sure that it is good design to have an unbounded array as cache key? I was thinking about hash code, but more in general cache keys should be small representative values by design. Large uncontrolled objects may occupy unjustified amounts of memory

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to tackle the issue using custom key generator support by Spring. What I did was, created a bean named cacheKeyGenearator and assigned a class to it, which was implementing KeyGenerator like:

```
    public class CacheKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator
    {
       @override
       public String generate(final Object target, final Method method, final Object... params)

      String key = "";
       // my code to configure key using different params
     return key;
     }
```

for xml part I did this:

```
    <cache:annotation-driven key-generator= "cacheKeyGenerator">
    <bean id ="cacheKeyGenerator" class ="com.cache.bean"/>

    //on my service level 
    @CacheConfig(keyGenerator="com.cache.bean")
    public class cacheServiceImpl implements cacheService
    {
     @overide
     @Cacheable(value="cacheStore")
     public String getSurName(String[] name) 
     // my code
    }
```